# Invalid child context `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to connect the state in the reducers to the components in my react components.
Here is the code of the reducer is in `reducer_books.js`:

```
export default function(){
  return [
      {title:'A'},
      {title:'E'}
  ];
}
```

Then, i added it to the combine reducer in `index.js`:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import BookReducer from './reducer_books';


const rootReducer= combineReducers({
  books:BookReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

At the end i tried to add it in the parent component:

```
import State from './reducer/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={State}>
      <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And in the target component i have:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class BookList extends Component{
  renderList(){
        return this.props.books.map((book)=>{
          <li key={book.title}>{book.title}</li>
        });
    }

  render(){

    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.renderList()}
        </ul>
      </div>);
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return{
    books:state.books
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

Unfortunately, it complains with:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`.
    in Provider (at index.js:11)
Warning: Failed childContext type: Invalid child context `store` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected `object`.
    in Provider (at index.js:11)
Warning: Failed context type: Invalid context `store` of type `function` supplied to `Connect(BookList)`, expected `object`.
    in Connect(BookList) (at App.js:35)
    in div (at App.js:33)
    in div (at App.js:32)
    in App (at index.js:12)
    in Provider (at index.js:11)
Uncaught TypeError: _this.store.getState is not a function
Error: Attempted to update component `Connect(BookList)` that has already been unmounted (or failed to mount)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example I don't see where you [**configure `Store`**](https://github.com/reactjs/redux#the-gist), I suppose that you missed this step

```
import reducers from './reducer/index';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const Store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ Store }>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```